# How to show that the force and velocity are perpendicular and that both have constant magnitude?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors

The force acting on a moving charged particle in a magnetic field $\hat{B}$ is $\hat{F}=q\left(\hat{v}\times \hat{B}\right)$ where $q$ is the electric charge of the particle, and $\hat{v}$ is its velocity. Suppose that a particle moves in the $\left(x,\:y\right)$ plane with a uniform $\hat{B}$ in the $z$ direction. Assuming Newton's second law, $\hat{F}=m\frac{d\hat{v}}{dt}$, how to show that the force and velocity are perpendicular and that both have constant magnitude? Should i evaluate the cross product on the RHS so the equation would be

$$\hat{F}=q\begin{pmatrix}\hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\v_x & v_y & v_z \\B_x & B_y & B_z\end{pmatrix}$$

$\left(F_x+qv_zB_y-qv_yB_z\right)\hat{\imath}+\left(F_y+qv_xB_z-qv_zB_x\right)\hat{\jmath}+\left(F_z+qv_yB_x-qv_xB_y\right)\hat{k}=0$

i don't know if this is correct or not & what's the physical meaning of this, how to show that the force and velocity are perpendicular? thank you so much!

Comment: Replace the $B_{x,y}$ with zero.

Comment: The cross product *always* produces a vector perpendicular to its two arguments.

Comment: Hi alethiologist. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: but this is not a homework, sir. i'm just curious with the answer. @Qmechanic

Comment: A hat is used for unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product of two vectors is always perpendicular to both vectors. So, the magnetic force $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ will always be perpendicular to $\vec{v}$. This can be seen in your special case by realizing thatsince the motion is in the $(x,y)$ plane $v_z=0$, and the only component of $\vec{B}$ that is not null is $B_z=B$, we have
$$F_x=qv_yB \\
F_y=-qv_xB$$
Hence, $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{F}=v_xF_x+v_yF_y=0$, and the vectors are orthogonal. To see that they have constant magnitude, we have the system of differential equations
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}m\dot{v}_x=qv_yB\\m\dot{v}_y=-qv_xB \end{array}\right.$$
This can be solved by substitution to give the solutions
$$v_x=v\sin\omega t\\
v_y=v\cos\omega t$$
with $\omega=\dfrac{qB}{m}$ and initial condition $\vec{v}(0)=v\hat{\jmath}$. So the motion is circular and the magnitude of the velocity $\|\vec{v}\|$ is constant to $v$, and so is for the force as $\|\vec{F}\|=qvB.$

Comment: this is a really helpful explanation. But i need time to grasp it, btw thank you so much, sir!

Comment: +1, plus the derivative of a vector is also perpendicular to the vector (this is a basic trick of moving frames differential geometry formulation)

Comment: This is true only for vectors of constant norm, since $\dot{\vec{x}}(t)\cdot \vec{x}(t)\neq0$ in general.

Comment: yeap, in moving frames normalised (unit) vectors are used